# How can I debug an if statement that isn't working?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, integer

I do not know what I did wrong.

```
def main():  # store anything to then replay code.
    import time

    math = int(input("Hi there, what is 32 + 16? =")) # asking what 32+16 is.

    if math == "48":
      print("Correct!") #this is the if statement that isn't working, suppose to say correct if the input is 48.

    else:
      print("Not quite..")  # this would come up instead of 'correct' if I would put 48.


    time.sleep(2)  # a delay
    restart=input('Do you wish to start again? ').lower()
    if restart == 'yes':  # if the player wants to play the game again.
      main()  # to replay code.

    else:
      exit()  # this wouldn't start the game again.


 main()  # this just starts main.
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. It will serve you in good stead.

Comment: Not related to the problem but nevertheless important: Don't use [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) (or `quit`). The documentation states: "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
if math == "48":
```

to this:

```
if math == 48:
```

You convert the input to int already.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be better served in a `while` loop as opposed to being enumerated at runtime?

To answer your question, you've already declared an integer, the quotes make python interpret it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You were super close but there are a few things that needed tweaking to get it working.

First, you will need to make sure that your main is defined correctly and remove the "**" from your code before the comments.

Second, the reason your code always fails the if statement check for if they got the correct answer is that you are casting the answer to an integer when you get the input, but then comparing it to a string version of 48, deleting the quotations around that should fix the issue as well.

I have implemented these and had the code working in python3 on my system.

Hope this helps (modified code below)

```
import time

def main():
  math = int(input("Hi there, what is 32 + 16? =")) #

  if math == 48:
    print("Correct!") #This is where I made the change, removing the 
                       quotes that surrounded the 48. 

  else:
    print("Not quite..")#this would come up instead of 'correct' if I 
                         would put 48.**


  time.sleep(2)#a delay**
  restart=input('Do you wish to start again? ').lower()
  if restart == 'yes':#if the player wants to play the game again.**
    main()#to replay code.**

  else:
    exit()#this wouldn't start the game again.**


main()#this just starts main.**
```

Comment: thank you everyone! :)